# Slick carousel not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js

New to web development and currently working with slick.js. Just trying to test out the code to see if it works, but my code appears as [text stacked on top of each other, rather than in the slideshow-carousel format I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbEjM.png)

Here is my code:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="your-class">
       <div>your content</div>
       <div>your content</div>
       <div>your content</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.your-class .one-time').slick({
    });
    </script>
    </body>
```

New to javascript so not sure what I'm doing wrong since I tried to follow the website's instructions exactly. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You also have no class called `.one-time` in your DOM

Comment: Try the CDN so you can make sure your files aren't corrupted:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css

Comment: Thanks! I clicked around to see if each of my links were working and figured out which files were not able to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer! For the href and src links, I had "slick/slick.css" and "slick/slick.min.js" - once I deleted the "slick/" part before the file name, the carousel was able to load correctly.

Comment: You can further customize the display of the slideshow by settings the `slidesToShow` attribute in the object you pass. If you wanted to show two it would be `$('.your-class .one-time').slick({slidesToShow:2});` See 'filtering' here: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/